# How to add and remove classes to the active slide child 'div' on react slick carousel

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

If you are on the active slide i want to add a className `content_animation` to the `className="content_text"`.

And if the slide changes whether you click/swipe the arrows or dots, the active slide will always do the same which is to add a className `content_animation` to the `className="content_text"`.

Im tyring to achieve it using `beforeChange` and/or `afterChange`.

Here is the [react slick docs](https://react-slick.neostack.com/)

Below is my code and also here is the complete sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/beforechange-afterchange-react-slick-hdvf4).

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default class SlideChangeHooks extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 1000,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      beforeChange: (oldIndex, newIndex) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const sample = document.querySelector(".content_text");
          sample.classList.remove("content_animation");
          console.log("beforeChange", oldIndex, newIndex);
        });
      },
      afterChange: (index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const sample = document.querySelector(".content_text");
          sample.classList.add("content_animation");
          console.log("afterChange", index);
        });
      }
    };
    return (
      <div className="slide-parent">
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div className="slide-item">
            <h3>1</h3>
            <div className="content_text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
          </div>
          <div className="slide-item">
            <h3>2</h3>
            <div className="content_text">Lorem Ipsum 2</div>
          </div>
          <div className="slide-item">
            <h3>3</h3>
            <div className="content_text">Lorem Ipsum 3</div>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const sample = document.querySelector(".content_text");
```

Because you use *document.querySelector* you take only one element, always the first, and a class never will be removed from other slides. You should use *document.querySelectorAll* to get all slides to remove the class from all slides.

```
 const sample = document.querySelector(".content_text");
```

Inside *afterChange* you should select only active slide and assign a class to it. Slick active slide has a class *.slick-active*

```
 beforeChange: (oldIndex, newIndex) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const sample = document.querySelectorAll(".content_text");

      for (let i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
        sample[i].classList.remove("content_animation");
        console.log("beforeChange", oldIndex, newIndex);
      }
      
    });
  },
  afterChange: (index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const sample = document.querySelector(".slick-active .content_text");
      sample.classList.add("content_animation");
      console.log("afterChange", index);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I just updated the sandbox base from your code and the content of the animation is flickering, if you have time, check my codesandbox link above.

Comment: It's because of setting animation class AFTER a slider changed. First slider is showed up, then animation is triggered

Comment: any workaround or possible solutions will help.

Comment: I got this check my updated code on sandbox link above and hopefully work on all browsers. thx!

Comment: I see. Yes, it works! And less code is needed, just append an animation class directly in the markup. And that will work in almost all browsers, because a CSS animation is highly supported. Please accept the answer, if it helped you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I got it check my updated code on sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beforechange-afterchange-react-slick-hdvf4) hopefully work on all browsers.

So for now i just removed the beforeChange and afterChange. By default the opacity of the text is 0 and then I update the opacity effects of the text from CSS targeting the `slick-active` or `slick-current` classes.

Still open for any workaround or possible solutions.